# How to factor $42x – 14x^3$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Is the polynomial factored correctly? Would appreciate your help. This is for my son who is just learning to factor polynomials.

The polynomial to be factored is given below:
$$42x – 14x^3$$

My attempt is:
$$
–14x^3 + 42x =  –14x(x^2–3)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also factor the $x^2-3$ term again into:

$$
(x^2 - 3) = (x + \sqrt{3})(x - \sqrt{3})
$$

Thus, your final version would be:

$$
42x - 14x^3 = -14x(x + \sqrt{3})(x - \sqrt{3})
$$

Comment: Thank you js9. He wants to confirm if he has to factor out the negative sign if leading coefficient is negative. Similarly in this problem 20 − 35n^2 − 20n^3: would he factor it as   -5( 4n^3 + 7n^2 - 4)?

Comment: @Pearl, no you do not have to. You can take out the negative factor outside at any step in the process, the result does not change. It is entirely up to your son's class convention.